# Is there a usual technical term for "category without any nonntrivial endomorphism"?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, definition

Is there a *usual* technical term in category theory for "category which does not have any non-identity endomorphism"? (Only that, no other condition imposed.)

Comment: I have seen $EId$-category based off of $EI$-category, but I don't claim this is standard or "usual".

Answer (score 1):

For finite categories, this is equivalent to being [direct](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+category), but is weaker for infinite categories. According to the nLab link, the condition you're asking about is sometimes called being a "one-way" category. I can't independently support this, but I think it's a pretty transparent term.